# Anova in R to fetch the significant codes

Tags: r, anova

Code:

```
pred_model = anova(m1, m2, test="Chisq")
pred_model
```

Results:

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: male_birth ~ male_death + female_birth + female_death
Model 2: male_birth ~ male_death + female_birth
Res.Df    RSS Df  Sum of Sq Pr(>Chi)
 1     48 3.4883                       
 2     49 3.4951 -1 -0.0068189   0.7594
```

I am new to R, can anyone suggest how to fetch the significant codes for the model

Comment: What do you mean? What do you want to fetch?

Comment: @user20650  `## Signif. codes: 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1.` The p-value.

Comment: If you have a look at `str(pred_model)` you can see the names of things that can be extracted from `pred_mode`, so for the pvalue you can use ``pred_model$`Pr(>Chi)`` . The stars are not retuned , but printed. You could capture the anova output, or mess about with the print methos that produces these, write your own wee function to convert the pvalue to signfance stars, or best of all omit the stars.

Comment: In fact, from looking at `printCoefmat` , you can generate the stars with: Extract the pvalue as shown in comment above and assign to object called `pv`: ``pv = pred_model$`Pr(>Chi)``, then generate the stars `symnum(pv, corr = FALSE, na = FALSE, 
                  cutpoints = c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1), 
                  symbols = c("***", "**", "*", ".", " "))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `summary` function will often return a matrix with a column of p-values. In this case, however, the result of `anova` is returned as a dataframe which has been further "class()-ed" as an "anova"-object (so that it can have its own `print`-method). Run the first example in `?lm` and then:

```
> lm.D9 <- lm(weight ~ group)
> lm.0 <- lm(weight ~ 1)

> anova(lm.D9,lm.0)
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: weight ~ group
Model 2: weight ~ 1
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1     18 8.7292                           
2     19 9.4175 -1  -0.68821 1.4191  0.249

> str( anova(lm.D9,lm.0) )
Classes ‘anova’ and 'data.frame':   2 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Res.Df   : num  18 19
 $ RSS      : num  8.73 9.42
 $ Df       : num  NA -1
 $ Sum of Sq: num  NA -0.688
 $ F        : num  NA 1.42
 $ Pr(>F)   : num  NA 0.249
 - attr(*, "heading")= chr  "Analysis of Variance Table\n" "Model 1: weight ~ group\nModel 2: weight ~ 1"
```

So you want the second value in the column named  that is named" `'Pr(>F)'`

```
anova(lm.D9,lm.0)$'Pr(>F)'[2]
[1] 0.2490232
```